# How to get default selected format from outlook in add-in using Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, outlook-api

If default format in outlook selected as a `html` or `Text` or `Rich Text`. So In `outlook add-in` how we fetch format from outlook setting using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`getTypeAsync`** function is use to get a selected format as `HTML` or `TEXT` and but for `RTF` format you get value as `HTML` instead of `RTF`.

`Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getTypeAsync(function (result) {
   ...
}`